# Android Studio Editor how to hide editor gradation remind?

Tags: android-studio, view, android-studio-3.0

[image: like this]

I want hide editor level remind,How to do this?

I tried (Main Menu-View-Active Editor) (Main Menu-Other) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

*Preferences* -> *Editor* -> *General* -> *Appearance* -> uncheck *Show Breadcrumbs*.